# What key-format and storage location to use for consul keys in microservices

Tags: configuration, microservices, consul, consul-kv

I am planning to use consul for storing key/value(configuration) for microservices, Now initially we stored the configuration(key and value) in JSON file, however since i am moving the value to consul , what is the best practice to store keys in microservices config, since the micorservices needs to be aware of which keys to access.
Also what key format should i use to differentiate between global setting in consul(the settings shared between different microservices) and private settings of individual microservices.

Answer (score 0):

Create a JSON under a key 'global', create a key for each service under its name with the JSON data it needs. Use both keys for each service.